# Static-content deploy runs only for en_US by default

Tags: localisation, magento2.2.2, static-content-deploy

Is it possible to set other local as default for static-content deploy command somehow?

I have "***he_IL***" store (This is single lang store and I set this lang at the installation, nothing was added after).
In spite of this when I run

> php bin/magento s:s:deploy -f

I should always additionally point he_IL.

> php bin/magento s:s:deploy -f he_IL

I know - this is not big deal, but anyway: can change this somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Within 2.1, the `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_VALUE` constant was used within `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentComand.php` to define the locale to deploy for if nothing was added as an option to the command line.

In 2.2 appears that this was overridden with `all` (`line 122`):

```
$options = $input->getOptions();
--> $options[Options::LANGUAGE] = $input->getArgument(Options::LANGUAGES_ARGUMENT) ?: ['all'];
$refreshOnly = isset($options[Options::REFRESH_CONTENT_VERSION_ONLY])
```

You could create an override for this to define your own default?

Comment: So, no options to just set this as environment path or maybe point somewhere in system config... 
I don't think if it's so important, that I need to override core command. By the way, it's a little bit strange that it doesn't select automatically, according to the store settings.